# Laravel and Eclipse: How to avoid errors in default code of Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, eclipse, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a new project in Laravel and I have opened it with the Eclipse IDE (for PHP), but I get an error in the default code generated by Laravel for the routes. How can I prevent this from happening?

[image]

I have only created the project and I have opened it with Eclipse and I have that error.

Comment: What's the exact error message you see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import the `Route` facade at the top of the file like `Request`.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

I recommend using this package, [barrydvh/ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper), in your projects. It generates a mapping of Laravel's facades and other static methods that the IDE has trouble with out of the box.

You'll need to install `Eclipse PHP plugin (PDT)`, as well.

Once you have everything setup, run:

```
php artisan ide-helper:generate
```

and refresh the project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not solve my problem. I have also installed arrydvh/ide-helper, but the IDE does not yet recognize the routes.

Comment: I do not see the need to use the namespace here, since in other IDE as PHPStorm is not necessary, I think I would be adding more code than necessary.

Comment: I use PhpStorm which built on top of Eclipse, it's most likely just a matter of configuration to get it working.

Comment: Make sure you have the `Eclipse PHP plugin (PDT)` installed too

Comment: I can not install PHPStorm because for now I do not have the money to buy it. That's why the Eclipse option. I have not been able to solve the problem.

Comment: And yes, I have Eclipse PHP Plugin installed (PDT)

Comment: @Ricky have you managed to surpass this problem? I'm struggling with the same thing, and can't find any answers to this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to Eclipse and just ran into the same problem  and solved it by creating a library. My Eclipse version is 2018-09 (4.9.0).

1. Firstly, require the [barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) package with
   composer using the following command:

   ```
   composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
   ```
2. Afterwards generate the _ide_helper.php with Artisan:

   ```
   php artisan ide-helper:generate
   ```
3. Copy the generated file into a directory outside of your workspace
4. In Eclipse switch to "Window/Preferences" and the select "PHP/Libraries"
5. Create a new library with "New..."
6. After creating it click on "Edit..." and check the checkbox "environment (added to the script environment"
7. Add the folder now to your library over "Add External Folder..."

Once the library is created you may need to delete all the entries in the "Problems" View and validate the project again.

Answer (score -2):

put

```
namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;
```

at the top of the file